# Insert missing document during _update_by_query

Tags: elasticsearch, insert-update

I have a mapping with 2 fields: message + weight.
'Message' is unique for each document.
I have to increment 'weight' each time document is retrieved.
If not found, I have to insert new document with default values.

Is there any way to automatically insert document, if not found, while running _update_by_query?

```
POST /testindex/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed
{
    "script": {
        "inline": "ctx._source.weight++",
        "lang": "painless"
    },
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "message": "iphone"
        }
    }
}
```

I need it to function like SQL: INSERT… ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Comment: No, update by query will only work on existing documents, unlike the update API which supports upserts. But in your example above, what document do you expect to be created on what condition since you don't specify an ID?

Comment: I have a mapping with 2 fields: message + weight. 'Message' is unique for each document. I have to increment 'weight' each time document is retrieved. If not found, I have to insert new document with default values.

Comment: in ideal, all should be done with 1 request

Comment: Would you mind using `message` as the document ID since it's unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your `message` field is unique for all documents, you can use it as the document ID. That would enable you to leverage the [Update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#upserts) and more specifically the upsert feature.

Basically, you can update a document (increment the `weight`) and if it doesn't exist it gets created (with `weight: 1`):

```
POST testindex/_doc/iphone/_update
{
    "script" : {
        "source": "ctx._source.weight++",
        "lang": "painless"
    },
    "upsert" : {
        "weight" : 1
    }
}
```

Comment: "source"->"inline" for my ES version (5.2)

Comment: Just checked combination of this solution with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52235605/elasticsearch-format-field-on-document-creation . I wanted to preprocess 'message' field, then pass it as a field + _id. Seems it can't work with pure ES. Even if I manage to normalize 'message', I can't pass its new value as an _id.

Comment: Nevertheless, your idea to use upsert+custom _id seem to solve most of my problem. Thanks!