# ElasticSearch Format field on document creation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a mapping with 1 field:

```
"message" : {
    "type" : "text"
}
```

I insert a new document:

```
"message" : " 123 "
```

Is it possible to change field text (trim) via ES functionality?
The purpose is to create a standard for field "message".
Clarification: Not to filter text for reverse index, but for original text.

Required output should be:

```
{
     "message" : "123"   
}
```

Comment: Are you saying, the source before getting document stored in ES should be modified?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve that using an [ingest pipeline](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) with a [`trim` processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/trim-processor.html).

First define the ingest pipeline:

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my-pipeline
{
  "description": "My ingest pipeline",
  "processors": [
    {
      "trim": {
        "field": "message"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then simply specify the pipeline to use when indexing your documents:

```
PUT my-index/doc/1?pipeline=my-pipeline
{
  "message": " 123 "
}
```

Then you can see that the leading and trailing whitespaces have been removed

```
GET my-index/doc/1
=>
{
  "message": "123"
}
```